# implementation 'com.github.rubenlagus:TelegramBots:6.7.0' Build APK getting Error

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I'm Trying build my APK using

> implementation 'com.github.rubenlagus:TelegramBots:6.7.0'

**this is my dependency**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.rubenlagus:TelegramBots:6.7.0'

}
```

and i got error like this

./gradlew assembleRelease

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app

WARNING:The option setting 'android.aapt2FromMavenOverride=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/android-sdk/build-tools/33.0.0/aapt2' is experimental.

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:mergeReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED

> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues FROM-CACHE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

> Duplicate class org.aopalliance.aop.Advice found in modules jetified-aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1 (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1) and jetified-spring-aop-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.27)

```
 Duplicate class org.aopalliance.aop.AspectException found in modules jetified-aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1 (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1) and jetified-spring-aop-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.ConstructorInterceptor found in modules jetified-aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1 (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1) and jetified-spring-aop-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.ConstructorInvocation found in modules jetified-aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1 (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1) and jetified-spring-aop-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.Interceptor found in modules jetified-aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1 (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1) and jetified-spring-aop-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.Invocation found in modules jetified-aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1 (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1) and jetified-spring-aop-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.Joinpoint found in modules jetified-aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1 (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1) and jetified-spring-aop-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor found in modules jetified-aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1 (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1) and jetified-spring-aop-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation found in modules jetified-aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1 (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.6.1) and jetified-spring-aop-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.Log found in modules jetified-commons-logging-1.2 (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and jetified-spring-jcl-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory found in modules jetified-commons-logging-1.2 (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and jetified-spring-jcl-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1 found in modules jetified-commons-logging-1.2 (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and jetified-spring-jcl-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog found in modules jetified-commons-logging-1.2 (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and jetified-spring-jcl-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog found in modules jetified-commons-logging-1.2 (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and jetified-spring-jcl-5.3.27 (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.27)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.ShiroException found in modules jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-lang-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-lang:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.cache.AbstractCacheManager found in modules jetified-shiro-cache-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-cache:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.cache.Cache found in modules jetified-shiro-cache-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-cache:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheException found in modules jetified-shiro-cache-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-cache:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheManager found in modules jetified-shiro-cache-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-cache:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheManagerAware found in modules jetified-shiro-cache-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-cache:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.cache.MapCache found in modules jetified-shiro-cache-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-cache:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager found in modules jetified-shiro-cache-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-cache:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.cache.package-info found in modules jetified-shiro-cache-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-cache:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.codec.Base64 found in modules jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-lang-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-lang:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.codec.CodecException found in modules jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-lang-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-lang:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.codec.CodecSupport found in modules jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-lang-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-lang:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.codec.H64 found in modules jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-lang-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-lang:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.codec.Hex found in modules jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-lang-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-lang:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.codec.package-info found in modules jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-lang-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-lang:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.CommonsInterpolator found in modules jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException found in the following modules: jetified-shiro-config-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-core:1.10.0), jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.DefaultInterpolator found in modules jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.Ini found in the following modules: jetified-shiro-config-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-core:1.10.0), jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.Ini$1 found in the following modules: jetified-shiro-config-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-core:1.10.0), jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.Ini$Section found in the following modules: jetified-shiro-config-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-core:1.10.0), jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.Interpolator found in modules jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder found in modules jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$1 found in modules jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$AssignmentStatement found in modules jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$BeanConfiguration found in modules jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$BeanConfigurationProcessor found in modules jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10.0)

 Duplicate class org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$InstantiationStatement found in modules jetified-shiro-config-ogdl-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:1.10.0) and jetified-shiro-core-1.10.0 (org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.10. 0)
```

.
.
.

Duplicate class org.telegram.telegrambots.util.WebhookUtils found in modules jetified-telegrambots-6.7.0 (com.github.rubenlagus.TelegramBots:telegrambots:6.7.0) and jetified-telegrambots-6.7.0 (org.telegram:telegrambots:6.7.0)

```
 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 6s

Whats wrong ?